# Why does my code not detect a match?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that is comparing a string against values in an array:

```js
var blacklistedSites = ['https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8'];
//Returns true if the current site is blacklisted, false otherwise
function isBlacklistedSite(url) {
    console.log('Site is ' + url);
    blacklistedSites.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log('testing ' + entry);
        if (entry == document.URL) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

console.log(isBlacklistedSite('https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8'));
```

This outputs:

```
Site is https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8
testing https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8
false
```

Why does `isBlacklistedSite()` not detect a match?

Comment: A `content_scripts` entry **does not** define your background page. It defines [*content scripts*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: It is not clear what your extension does when a blacklisted site is encountered. However, it is likely that using a content script to detect the URL is not a good solution.  You should look into using a [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) listener.

Comment: I have edited your question much more extensively than I would normally. There was quite a bit of extraneous information in the question, which really was not relevant to your actual problem. Obviously, I feel it is a better question with the edit. However, it is your question, so feel free to rollback the edit to the prior version, if you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that your:

```js
return true;
```

effectively does nothing. It just returns from the `forEach` function, which happens anyway regardless of there being a match, or not. Your `return true;` does not return from your `isBlacklistedSite()` function. Your `isBlacklistedSite()` function *always* exits with:

```js
return false;
```

While you could do this using `.forEach()`, it is a poor choice. The `.forEach()` method *always* iterates over *every* member of the array, regardless of any return value you provide in the `forEach` function. You would only use it if you were also doing some other operation on every element of the array at the same time. Even then, it might be better to separate out the two different tasks. If you did use it, you would have to keep the detection in a variable defined external to the `.forEach(function(){...`.

#### Use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to test an exact match to an array element

If you want to test for *exact* matches of Array elements, you can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and test for a value > -1.

For instance:

```js
var blacklistedSites = ['https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8'];
function isBlacklistedSite(url) {
    console.log('Site is ' + url);
    return blacklistedSites.indexOf(url) > -1;
}

//Test with a known matching value.
console.log(isBlacklistedSite(blacklistedSites[0]));
//Test with a known failing value.
console.log(isBlacklistedSite('foo'));
```

#### If you need a more complex test, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var blacklistedSitesRegExes = [/(?:https?:)?\/\/[^/]*www\.google\.com\/.*espv=2/];
function isBlacklistedSite(url) {
    console.log('Site is ' + url);
    return blacklistedSitesRegExes.some(function(regex){
        regex.lastIndex = 0; //Prevent contamination from prior tests
        return regex.test(url);
    });
}

//Test with a known matching value.
console.log(isBlacklistedSite('https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8'));
//Test with a known failing value.
console.log(isBlacklistedSite('foo'));
```

#### With [limited availability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility): [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (not for production code)

`.includes()` does exactly what you want (return a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) `true`/`false` for an exact match). However, it is not as [generally available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) as `.indexOf()`. It is recommended not to use it in production code. For Arrays, it does not add much benefit over `.indexOf(url) > -1`.

#### Additional [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)

There are many additional methods available to [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which could be used to determine that you have a match. What you use will depend on your specific needs. As always, you should be mindful of compatibility issues for any method you choose to use. Some of the available methods are ([text from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)):

- [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
  Returns true if every element in this array satisfies the provided testing function.
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
  Creates a new array with all of the elements of this array for which the provided filtering function returns true.
- [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ([no IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility))
  Returns the found value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function or undefined if not found.
- [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) ([no IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility))
  Returns the found index in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function or -1 if not found.
- [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) ([compatibility issues, including no IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility))
  Determines whether an array contains a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
  Returns the first (least) index of an element within the array equal to the specified value, or -1 if none is found.
- [Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)
  Returns the last (greatest) index of an element within the array equal to the specified value, or -1 if none is found.
- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
  Returns true if at least one element in this array satisfies the provided testing function.

Could be used, but not very appropriate:

- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
  Calls a function for each element in the array.
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
  Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
  Apply a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) as to reduce it to a single value.
- [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)
  Apply a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from right-to-left) as to reduce it to a single value.